# Agregar un <Div> en sidebar AdminLTE 3 | Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, adminlte

Hola estoy aprendiendo Laravel8,

He buscado en la [documentacion de adminLTE3](https://adminlte.io/docs/3.0/components/main-sidebar.html) la forma de modificar el dashboard pero no encuentro como agregar un contenedor dentro del sidebar.

***Edit:***
He implementado adminLTE con el motor de plantillas Blade y utilizo el paquete [jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE).

He visto en la [doc de adminLTE2 con python y django](https://django-adminlte2-templates.readthedocs.io/en/latest/template_blocks/layouts.html#sidebar) que agrega un contenedor para publicidad o redireccion a otro lado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi archivo `config/adminlte.php`

He modificado el menú de navegación, pero es posible agregar un bloque de html aquí directamente? o puedo mostrar una view aquí dentro?

```
'menu' => [
        [
            'text' => 'Buscar',
            'search' => true,
            'topnav' => true,
        ],
        [
            'text'        => 'Inicio',
            'url'         => 'dash',
            'icon'        => 'fas fa-fw fa-home',
            'label_color' => 'success',
        ],
        [
            'text' => 'Contáctanos',
            'url'  => 'dash/contact',
            'icon' => 'fas fa-fw fa-envelope',
        ], 
    ],

    <> CONTENEDOR POR EJEMPLO</>
```

Agradecería cualquier comentario,

Comment: Como has implementado adminlte a tu proyecto? Lo digo, ya que lo usual es usar blade

Comment: Hola Juan, gracias por tu comentario, ya he editado la pregunta y en efecto, he usado blade para implementar adminLTE.

Comment: Ya entiendo, lo decia porque tenias un "`config/adminlte.php`" y eso es de una dependencia como " jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE" correcto? Si es asi, puedes hacer un "publish" de las vistas para modificar manualmente el sidebar

Comment: Es exactamente de jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE, que vi en Github. No entiendo lo que es un publish, pero voy a investigar. Gracias.

Comment: Agrega ese detalle a tu pregunta, de que estas usando esa dependencia

Comment: Y sobre del publish, por lo que vi, jeroennoten lo hace de otra forma, cree una respuesta en base a lo que pides Ademas de que tambien me corrigo, no es una dependencia, sino un paquete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer este tipo de modificaciones, tienes que "customizar" la vista, para ello, segun la [documentacion](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/wiki/Views-Customization) tienes que ejecutar el siguiente comando para poder exportar todas las vistas que trae ese paquete, con el fin de modificar el sidebar:

```
php artisan adminlte:install --only=main_views
```

Esto estara en tu `resources/views/vendor`, entonces en la vista sidebar puedes agregar lo que quieres, pero ten en cuenta la advertencia avisan al customizar:

> Importante: si publica las vistas del paquete, le recomendamos que siga el procedimiento de actualización que se explica en la sección Actualización si una nueva versión de este paquete incluye cambios en estas vistas.

Comment: Hola Juan, Gracias por la respuesta, voy a revisarlo y te comento, antes estoy haciendo un backup del proyecto.